Chrome measuring FPS incorrect

I'm measuring the performance of an animation. When i use the following code to measure FPS, it's inconsistent with Chrome Frame rendering stats.
let lastTime = performance.now();
let lastFrameTime = performance.now();
let frame = 0;
let fps = 0;

const loop = function () {
  const now = performance.now();
  const fs = now - lastFrameTime;
  lastFrameTime = now;
  frame++;
  if (now > 1000 + lastTime) {
    fps = Math.round((frame * 1000) / (now - lastTime));
    frame = 0;
    lastTime = now;
    //If delete this statement, the stats is incorrect
    el.innerText = "FPS: " + fps;
    console.log(fps);
  }
  window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
};
loop();

I found the reason. If delete el.innerText = "FPS: " + fps, the result will be wrong. Click here to view demo.
Reproduce

Open Console (Click right-top icon "Chrome DevTools for the preview")
Click switch button in the  top-right of the preview. (The FPS of the page and the FPS in the Console are the same)
Delete code el.innerText = "FPS: " + fps;
Repeat 1 and 2 （The FPS of the Console is wrong.）


I would not expect that you can achieve the same results. I think the dev tools run in parallel to the site, your script will run directly in the site context.
